# Is this state update Actor pattern supported in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

Let's say I have an actor that receives data and I want to use the data to update the Actor's state, but the order in which state updates does not matter. So I have an actor whose sole responsibility is to update this state - it receives a message `UpdateState(oldState: State, data: RawData)` and returns `UpdatedState(state: State)`. I also have an actor that takes `ValidateState(state)` that validates that state is correct. Correctness is checking for errors in the data.

Right now I have the following:

```scala
object MyActor {

    var curState: State = initialState

    sealed trait MyActorCommand
    final case class Data(rawData: String) extends MyActorCommand
    final case class UpdatedState(state: State) extends MyActorCommand

    def apply(): Behavior[MyActorCommand] = Behaviors.receive { (_, message) => 
    message match {
        case Data(rawData) => stateUpdater ! UpdateState(curState, rawData)
        case UpdatedState(state) => curState = state; validator ! ValidateState(state)
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeing the following behavior: `stateUpdater` always receives the initial state, and the state validator always has a state that only takes the last data into account. Why does `curState` fail to update?

Comment: There isn't enough code here to tell what is going on. Where is the `var` defined? Where is that `match` call happening? More to the point is this a classic actor or typed?

Comment: Typed actor, var is defined inside the actor object

Comment: In which case why are you using a `var` rather than returning a modified `Behaviour`  from the message handler?

Comment: How would I do that? Would the actor return a Behavior? Or would I have a function in this actor that returned the Behavior?

Comment: I can't store the state easily on the stateUpdater because the state has a context of the entity for which it is tracking state, whereas the stateUpdater handles data for all entities.